# Constructor undefined error

Tags: java, constructor

This code is taken from variety of sources that provide answers to an old MIT course. I can't get it to compile. How do I alter this code to remove the "The constructor Book(String) is undefined" error?

```
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.util.*;

public class Library {
    String libraryAddress;
    ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(); 

    public Library(String address) {
        libraryAddress = address;
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        books.add(book);
    }

    public void printAddress() {
        System.out.println(libraryAddress);
    }

    public static void printOpeningHours() {
        System.out.println("Libraries are open daily from 9am to 5pm.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create two libraries
        Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St.");
        Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St.");

        // Add four books to the first library
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Da Vinci Code"));
        //firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Le Petit Prince"));
        //firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Tale of Two Cities"));
        //firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Lord of the Rings"));

        // Print opening hours and the addresses
        System.out.println("Library hours:");
        printOpeningHours();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Library addresses:");
        firstLibrary.printAddress();
        secondLibrary.printAddress();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `import java.awt.print.Book;` the right import?

Comment: You need Book class and import this to your code. If you only want to compile, coment all line that uses Book class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the wrong import 
`import java.awt.print.Book;`

Remove this import and you need to import the Book class that was present in your package.

Book Class example according to your code:

```
public class Book {
    String bookName;

    public Book(String name) {
        this.bookName = name;
    }
}
```

You need to add this class and import this into your Library class

Comment: Many thanks. I'm using Eclipse and stupidly had built the two classes in different packages

Comment: No worries. At some point It happened to everyone. :) If you think this is helpful please mark this as accepted answer

Comment: Could I ask a follow on question ? How could I have made use of the class if it wasn't in the same package?

Comment: If you declare the class's visiblity as Public then it can be accessed outside of the package